# Why is mono inside switchIfEmpty not being executed?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

In the below code logic, the `someFunction()` is called but the mono inside `functionThree` never gets executed. Even thought the "Valid" is logged but the returned mono from repository is never executed. Why is that, even though I have subscribed the mono in SomeFunction()?

```java
SomeFunction() {
    return functionOne(param).flatMap(param -> functionTwo(param)).then(Boolean.TRUE::toString).subscribe();
}
Mono<Integer> functionOne(int param) {
    return Mono.just(param);
}
Mono<List<Integer>> functionTwo(int param) {
    return Mono.just(param)
    .filter(param -> param != 1)
    .switchIfEmpty(functionThree(param));
}

Mono<List<Integer>> functionThree(int param) {
    log.info("Valid");
    return reactiveStream.findById(param)
    .map(obj -> {
        log.info("INSIDE STREAM");
        return obj.getId;
    })
    .collectList();
}
```

Comment: Because that setup before it is not empty. It would be empty if `param == 1`.

Comment: @akarnokd yes param is 1 only. Still it is not getting executed.

Comment: How do you tell it does not execute? Try putting the call to `functionThree` into a deferred source: `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> functionThree(param)))`.

Comment: @akarnokd yes still not executed, I have tried with defer. And How do I tell it did not execute, please check the edited version now, the statement is not logged.

Comment: Time to put `doOnNext`s all over the place with logging to see where it stops.

Comment: Already tried, doesn't even log after the repository call @akarnokd

Comment: Add them between every operator you have, after just, after switchIfEmpty, after filter, after flatMap, etc. Also how are you calling `SomeFunction()`?

Answer (score 0):

As comment said, Because that setup before it is not empty. the "Valid" logged and executed at assembly stage. Even if you don't subscribed, it always execute it.